# How to set the output type of a function literal?

Tags: scala

I am mapping spark [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row) objects, each with one item per row, to an Array. Given an input `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` object `spark_rows`:

```
val array_object = spark_rows.map( (r: Row) => {r.toSeq.head} )
```

The output of this is an `Array[Any]` object. But I know that all the members of these rows are Strings, I want the output object to be `Array[String]`. How can I do this?

Based on the way you define functions, I tried

```
val array_object = spark_rows.map( (r: Row): String => {r.toSeq.head} )
```

but this does not work.

Comment: `map(_.toSeq.head.toString)`  ?

Comment: @jwvh Great for string, but doesn't work for Any -> Double. I suppose I could do `.toString.toDouble` Is there a more generalized answer that works for any type?

Comment: That's a different question, and the answer is no. If `array_object` **might be** `String`, and it **might be** `Double`, then what it actually **is** is `Any`, and you're right back where you started.

Comment: I never really know what the benefit of Row is.

Comment: @thebluephantom, when a DataFrame or Dataset is transformed to a RDD, it becomes a RDD[Row].  A `Row` is just a "container" of items of various types (sort of like a Scala Tuple) and is equipped with a bunch of methods for manipulating items it consists of.

Comment: Hi Leo. But I cannot use groupByKey etc. So I am never sure, for structured data, what the benefit is of the conversion to RDD. That insight eludes me.

Comment: Agreed that one rarely needs to transform from a DataFrame/Dataset to a RDD[Row].  But when needed (say, to create a continuous unique index column using RDD zipWithIndex), those `Row` methods do come handy.

Comment: Gotcha, just what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Row` method `toSeq` returns a `Seq[Any]` hence the said problem.  If you want to retrieve a particular item of known type out of a `Row`, use [getAs[T](index)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Row@getAs[T](i:Int):T) as shown below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val df = Seq(
  (1, "a", 1.0),
  (2, "b", 2.0)
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3")

val rdd = df.rdd
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = ...

rdd.map(_.getAs[Int](0))
// res1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]

rdd.map(_.getAs[String](1))
// res2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

rdd.map(_.getAs[Double](2))
// res3: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question in the title: use type ascription.

Without ascription:

```
scala>  val foo = (i: Int) => Set.empty
foo: Int => scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing] = $$Lambda$funnyNumber1
```

with ascription:

```
scala> val foo = (i: Int) => (Set.empty: Set[Int])
foo: Int => Set[Int] = $$Lambda$funnyNumber2
```